# How to deploy app in this meteor docker image?

Tags: docker

I am tring to use https://github.com/CyCoreSystems/docker-meteor to run my meteor app.

I successfully built the docker image from Dockerfile in the github repository.

One issue I have now is I am not sure what commands to run the docker image.

There are not many instructions about how to use the image.

If I simply run `docker run -i -t ulexus/meteor /bin/bash`, there will be an error complaining '/var/www/main.js' not found.

But how can I copy my meteor app source into the container without running the container?

Maybe I need to use something like the example in the instruction: 
`docker run --rm -e ROOT_URL=http://testsite.com -e REPO=https://github.com/yourName/testsite -e BRANCH=testing -e MONGO_URL=mongodb://mymongoserver.com:27017 ulexus/meteor`

But my app repo is a private one rather than public in github. Not sure how to specify my username/password in the command.

==========

The Dockerfile I used to create the image is this:

```
# DOCKER-VERSION 1.2.0
# METEOR-VERSION 1.0.0
FROM stackbrew/ubuntu:trusty
RUN apt-get update
### For latest Node
RUN apt-get install -y software-properties-common
RUN add-apt-repository -y ppa:chris-lea/node.js
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y build-essential nodejs
###
### For standard Ubuntu Node
#RUN apt-get install -y build-essential nodejs npm
#RUN ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node
###
# Install git and curl
RUN apt-get install -y git curl
# Make sure we have a directory for the application
RUN mkdir -p /var/www
RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www
# Install fibers -- this doesn't seem to do any good, for some reason
RUN npm install -g fibers
# Install Meteor
RUN curl https://install.meteor.com/ |sh
# Install entrypoint
ADD entrypoint.sh /usr/bin/entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod +x /usr/bin/entrypoint.sh
# Add known_hosts file
ADD known_hosts /root/.ssh/known_hosts
EXPOSE 80
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/bin/entrypoint.sh"]
CMD []
```

===========

Error messages after run `docker run -i -t ulexus/meteor /bin/bash`:

```
Unable to locate server directory; hold on: we're likely to fail

module.js:340
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module '/var/www/main.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:906:3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not really sure what you mean to do with your command `docker run -i -t ulexus/meteor /bin/bash` because with the `-i`, `-t` and `/bin/bash` at the end, this just starts the image and runs an interactive bash session. How does this create the `main.js` error? What does your Dockerfile look like? I use the following command to run a test-server that starts a simple `sshd` process: `docker run -p 22:22 --rm=true --name sshd-server sshd`. Here the image named (in your case ulexus/meteor) `sshd` is started and the resulting container's name is `sshd-server`. It's important to note that the `/bin/bash` command is missing on the end, as well as the `-i`, `-t` and that you have a `CMD` entry in your Dockerfile. Here's mine `CMD ["/usr/sbin/sshd", "-D"]` and here's a copy of the Dockerfile itself:

```
FROM debian:wheezy

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get upgrade

RUN apt-get -y install openssh-server
RUN echo 'root:root' | chpasswd
RUN mkdir /var/run/sshd

CMD ["/usr/sbin/sshd", "-D"]

EXPOSE 22
```

Your [CMD](http://docs.docker.com/reference/builder/#cmd) entry should be something that starts meteor.

And then your `docker` command would look something like this:

```
docker run -p hostPort:containerPort --rm ulexus/meteor
```

Notice again that `-i`, `-t`, and `/bin/bash` are missing. The `hostPort:containerPort` is so that I can open a network (`ssh`) connection to the container.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Also, the `--rm` is mostly a convenience thing. I like to throw away containers after I stop them, so that starting a new image doesn't mean I have to pick a new name.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. 

I added the Dockerfile I used in the original question. 

I run `docker run -i -t ulexus/meteor /bin/bash` because I want to login the running container and then to `git pull` my meteor app source code and run the meteor service.

Comment: Ah, then this is probably more of a problem with your `entrypoint.sh` than with docker. Can you post the contents of that file, or any error messages that are thrown? Once you get `entrypoint.sh` working from your bash in your container, it should work when you run the container with the `run` command.

Comment: I added the error messages. I cannot run the container, so I don't know how to access entrypoint.sh.

Comment: Ok, so I can't even get the Dockerfile to build on my linux, but you can start by overriding the entrypoint with `--entrypoint` when you start the container. Something like `docker run -i -t --entrypoint=/bin/bash ulexus/meteor` should do the trick

Comment: I also see that their entrypoint.sh supports [deploy keys](https://developer.github.com/guides/managing-deploy-keys/), but I can't figure out how it's supposed to work. It looks like they are expecting GITHUB_DEPLOY_KEY to be an executable or something. If you do something like `ADD /path/to/deploy_key /` in the Docker file, then `build` the container again and run it like so `docker run -e DEPLOY_KEY='/deploy_key' -p hostPort:containerPort --rm ulexus/meteor` (note, not GITHUB_DEPLOY_KEY) then it should be able to clone your private repo.

Comment: I went ahead and implemented the suggested changes on my version [here](https://github.com/flooose/docker-meteor/commit/667e6318e732976ed7946f7c9b396c8cb7f6fcd6), if you want to try to work with that.

Comment: I am not sure how to use deploy_key, while the `--entrypoint` does help me run the container. Thanks for your works, @flooose.

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative solution, try this: https://github.com/chriswessels/meteor-tupperware

It'll let you turn your Meteor.js app into a lean, production-ready Docker image with very little effort.

From the Usage docs:

> ## Quickstart
>
> In your Meteor.js project directory, run the following command:
>
> `curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/chriswessels/meteor-tupperware/master/quickstart.sh > /tmp/quickstart.sh && sh /tmp/quickstart.sh`
>
> This script will write a Dockerfile and .dockerignore into your current directory, preconfigured as below.
>
> After running the quickstart script, and assuming you have Docker running, you can build an image of your Meteor.js app by running:
>
> `docker build -t yourname/app .`

Disclaimer: I'm the author of this tool.